# Database backup on Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, database-backups, sql-data-warehouse

is there any way to backup the database say **'ABC'** and then restoring with the name **'ABC_Old'** on *Azure SQL Data Warehouse*?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you are going to downvote me, please give me a reason why you are doing it. It will give me constructive criticism which will allow me to better frame questions in the future.

Comment: Don't know about the downvotes, but the closure votes are for being Too Broad.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a new SQL Data Warehouse via the portal, then selecting `Backup` as the source then configuring the backup options?

[image: Azure portal]

See here for info on the restore operation generally:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-restore-database-portal

Comment: I followed steps from the link given, but getting this error: **Restoring SQL database failed in resource group <<resource group name>>**

Comment: Are you giving the database a different name?  Have you tried creating in a different filegroup?

Comment: I followed the link you provided. And yes, I am renaming the DB name to the 'ABC_Old' and performing a point in time restore.

Comment: Different resource group?  Consider contacting support via the portal if that doesn't work.

Comment: Resource group is the same.

Comment: *Solved*. Found out that I did not had the sufficient permission for the resource group.